# How do I repeat table headers per record on mobile (create a stacked view on mobile)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootstrap.  I'm using bootstrap 3.  I'm trying to figure out how I can create the following so that it looks like a standard table when not viewing it on a mobile device, and in a more stacked fashion when on mobile.

This is what I'm wanting to do:

[image: Example of what I'm looking to do]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to your code mention in two different table. & then use css class [.hidden-xs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) & [.visible-xs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) for show & hide in responsive and non-responsive view.

Example following code. also, check it here in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mp8px0qh/)

```
<!--Non-Mobile-->
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover hidden-xs">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>DOMAIN</td>
      <td>USER</td>
      <td>ACCT</td>
      <td>STATUS</td>
      <td>ACTIONS</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>domain1.co</td>
      <td>user1</td>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td>active</td>
      <td>edit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>domain2.co</td>
      <td>user1</td>
      <td>654321</td>
      <td>active</td>
      <td>edit</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!--Responsive-->
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover visible-xs">
  <tr>
    <td>DOMAIN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>domain1.co</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>USER</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>user1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ACCT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123456</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>STATUS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>active</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ACTIONS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>edit</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover visible-xs">
  <tr>
    <td>DOMAIN</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>domain2.co</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>USER</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>user1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ACCT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>654321</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>STATUS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>active</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ACTIONS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>edit</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```